# How to detect closed socket on asyncio.StreamWriter.write?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I've finally gotten around to learning python's `asyncio`, and am creating a simple client-server.  I can easily use `open_connection` and `start_server` and get everything talking.  However, I've run into some unexpected behavior detecting when one side closes the connection unexpectedly.

On the client-side, I can easily detect the server closed the connection because any call to `StreamReader.read` being awaited either errors or returns nothing.  However, a `StreamWriter.write`/`await StreamWriter.drain` call seems to succeed regardless of whether the other side still has the socket open or not, and this is what confuses me.

Client (in a coroutine which is called via `run_until_complete`:

```
_, writer = await asyncio.open_connection('127.0.0.1', 1234)
_ = input('Connected.  Type and press enter to attempt send.')

try:
    writer.write(b'A message')
    await writer.drain()
    print('Sent successfully.')

except:
    print(traceback.print_exc())
finally:
    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()
```

Server (synchronous version, I've also tried an async server):

```
with socket.socket() as s:
    s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 1234))
    s.listen(1)

    con, addr = s.accept()
    with con:
        print(f'Connected to {addr[0]}:{addr[1]}')
        _ = input('Type and press Enter to close.')
```

If I start the server, connect the client, then have the server terminate the connection, then tell the client to write, I would expect based on the documentation and [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779956/why-should-asyncio-streamwriter-drain-be-explicitly-called) to receive an exception, but instead the client just prints `Sent successfully.`  Tested with Python 3.7.6 and Python 3.8.1.

I'm aware that this won't matter in many actual applications, as you're likely to have a read-loop of some sort so you'd get know about the issue from a call to `StreamReader.read`.  That much said, I'm at a loss as to why I'm unable to detect the failure on `write`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to implement is incompatible with how TCP sockets work. Your `drain()` succeeds not because of an asyncio peculiarity, but because the underlying `write()` succeeds. OS-level writing succeeds because it is buffered by the kernel for efficiency.

If you want to detect that the client is still there, you will need to design a protocol that requires it to respond to the write, and detect eof while reading that response. But even so, you will need a timeout while reading, as there is no guarantee that the client's disconnect will always be "clean" and result in a shutdown signal.

Comment: in some cases asyncio.sleep(5) and check helps to avoid big busy waiting.